# javascript two conditions in if statement

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write code that checks two conditions in an if statement but no luck.

```
for(var num = 1; num<=100;num +=1)
{if (num % 3==0) and (num % 5==0) console.log("fizzbuzz");
    else if (num % 3==0) console.log("fizz");
    else if(num % 5==0) console.log("buzz");
    else console.log(num);}
```

Comment: Indentation and proper formatting will go a long way.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&&` instead of *and*.

```js
for (var num = 1; num <= 50; num += 1) {
  if (num % 3 == 0 && num % 5 == 0) console.log("fizzbuzz");
  else if (num % 3 == 0) console.log("fizz");
  else if (num % 5 == 0) console.log("buzz");
  else console.log(num);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, change `and` to `&&`,
Also, your `if` statement does not have parenthesis like that:

```
for(var num = 1; num<=100;num +=1){
    if ((num % 3==0) && (num % 5==0)) console.log("fizzbuzz");
    else if (num % 3==0) console.log("fizz");
    else if(num % 5==0) console.log("buzz");
    else console.log(num);
}
```

Then it should work like a charm!
You need to work your indentation too.

Answer (score 1):

1. Indentation. If you use IDE (like webstorm), there should be an option to auto format the code. FYI: indentation plays a very big role in understanding your own code in some time (for example, right after you write it:))
2. I wouldn't call it js becase there's logical AND operator: `&&`, not `and`. At first glance it can be even treated as a portion of pseudocode, bad pseudocode
3. `if` statement has structure like `if (condition) operator`, so when you want to check multiple conditions, you should wrap them with parenthesis: `if (condition1 && condition2 && ... && conditionN)`. All the conditions are finally equvalent to a single condition that's checked after evaluation.
4. Of course, `if` statement allows you **not** to wrap operators with curly brases: `if (condition) some operator;`. But it's more readable and understandable if you write `if (condition) {operator}`. For example, when you change your code and want to add some more operators, it will be more secured from some confusing mistakes. Let's say you want to write smth like this:

`if(everythingIsOk)informUser;`

Let's say you'd like to add a message if everything is ok. You could write this:

```
if (everythingIsOk)
    informUser;
    writeMessage;
```

In the example above you make the program to write the message anyway because it's a separate instruction. If you wrote initially `if (everythingIsOk){informUser}` it would be easier to just add one more instruction that must be executed in this particular case. More than that, it's more readable.

You would probably be surprised, but the following is valid too:

```
if (everythingIsOk);
```

The following is more readable because at least it makes people think that you haven't forgotten about your construction somewhere in the middle:

```
if (everythingIsOk){}
```

And finally, if you want to emphasize that nothing should be done in some cases, that's the approach (just fyi):

```
if (everythingIsOk){/* Do nothing, no code here is not a mistake! */}
```

So your code would be more readable if you wrote it like this:

```
for (var num = 1; num <= 100; num += 1) {
    if ((num % 3 == 0) && (num % 5 == 0)) {
        console.log("fizzbuzz");
    } else if (num % 3 == 0) {
        console.log("fizz");
    } else if (num % 5 == 0) {
        console.log("buzz");
    } else {
        console.log(num);
    }
}
```

5. I'd recommend you read at least examples you learn more accurately.